# Include headers which is in an external package

Tags: ros, include, manifest.xml, header, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'd like to ask how to include headers in an external package.
I created a package as followings.

```
・package name: test
・include/test/test.hpp↓
  #ifndef _TEST
  #define _TEST
　#include <iostream>
　
　void test(void);
  #endif
・src/test.cpp↓
  #include "test/test.hpp"

  void test(void)
  {
    std::cout << "test\n";
  }
```

I added "rosbuild_add_libraries(test src/test.cpp)" in the manifest.xml for it
and lib/test.so was successfully created.

In this case, how do I should include header "test.hpp" in other packages ?
I added " in manifest.xml in other packages, however rosmake failed.
What should I do?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32296/include-headers-which-is-in-an-external-package/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need put your include path into the export tag of the manifest of "test" as well.
See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest and [cflags in the -Tag documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html#export).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone else that ends up here, see:

answers.ros.org/question/12972/how-to-include-other-packages-headers/

For an example solution.

---

Originally posted by [captnPlan3t](https://answers.ros.org/users/4530/captnplan3t/) with karma: 21 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2